# how to allocate & deallocate memory in php?

Tags: php, php-internals

I'm trying to allocate memory dynamically in my code and release them ,I tried to use `zend_mm` but I couldn't add it to `php` 7,I'm using `php` 7.4 and `xampp` server , if it is impossible please tell my the Alternatives to do that.

the problem is ,I try to use `rundll` to execute some c functions from `dll` library ,but the `rundll` doesn't return output from functions so ,I try to reserve some memory from ram and run the `rundll` command by exec() `php` function ,passing the address to reversed memory to function, then the function writes its output on this memory so ,I can get the output after the function ends

steps :
1- `php` reserve some memory from ram .
2- `php` open `cmd` and run the `rundll` to call c function.
3- c function writes output in reserved memory .
4- `php` can got the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Memory Allocation and Deallocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816767/php-memory-allocation-and-deallocation)

Comment: @kavigun This doesn't seem to be related. He's trying to interface with an external DLL, not just using PHP variables.

Comment: `exec()` is for running shell commands, it creates a new process and doesn't use the memory of the current process.

Comment: `zend_mm` as I understand is a part of PHP's internals, so it's there already. PHP automatically allocates blocks of memory, in response to what your code is doing, up to the limit of your `memory_limit`. I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box means for custom memory allocation and access. Is there no other way you can return output from your dll? Could write a wrapper for it that returns the output to PHP.

Comment: no this link isn't useful there are to different things , here i want to make like new and delete in c++ or alloc() and free() in c . i want to use the memory freely reserving it and freeing it by myself

Comment: Sounds like you want to be writing a PHP extension, not PHP code.